# How to show multiple products in detail view on custom page?

Tags: magento2, products

I want to show multiple products in full detail view on a custom page. Please, anyone, suggest to me the steps to follow for achieving that idea. my Magento version is 2.3. The screenshot is attached for a detailed view product.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is something interesting for me as well!! Generally you need to use catelog_category_view.xml code with product detail page view and custom product collection query. I would recommend to follow  below basic instruction.

1. create a custom layout let's say yourpackage/yourmodule/view/frontent/layout/.xml
2. in <layout.xml> copy code from "catalog_category_view.xml" and change main phtml file to your module phtml file. change class which extends to "Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" and remove unnecessary code which you don't need.
3. Set default grid view to list view and and modify query to get attribute you want with 5 product to display as product details view.
4. now modify your phtml file as per your design.

Hope it helps!